# Control Games running on Windows over network (and use ESC key)

Tags: steam, technical-issues, linux, networking

I have one (Windows 8.1) PC set up for gaming only, and I can control that for the most part using VNC from Linux. The problem is however that controling the mouse in games (Tested using Dragon Age: Origins and Deus Ex: Human Revolution) moves the mouse in 'blocks'. Instead of smoothly moving the mouse like on the desktop, it behaves as if there was a 'move camera 3cm to the left/right/up/down' command. How could I make the mouse move smoothly?

---

My second question would be why the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key does not work? I assume it is some sort of 'security' feature, but I kinda need it for menus to work (<kbd>Win+X</kbd> also does not work... ). Is there something I can do here?

The entire point of this is to use my Linux Laptop as a controller. I am using VNC currently as that was the easiest to set up, however I am open to using other programs (remember, they do not necessarily have to steam video to my laptop, just allow me to control the game running on the other computer).

Comment: If the VNC client resolution differs from the host resolution, then this might account for the positional differences, you might also experiment by disabling mouse acceleration etc on BOTH systems.

Comment: // , Why the downvotes? Seriously? I'm voting this up. It includes a concise description of a technical issue, and specific question, which, if need be, can be pointed in a different direction. @Michael, add the linux tag and the steam tag to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to go here is to use Steam's [in-home Streaming Feature](http://store.steampowered.com/streaming).
It is specifically build to play games remotely from one computer in a home network while it is run on another. This also works with other games [that are not native to Steam](http://www.pcgamer.com/valve-open-up-in-home-streaming-to-non-steam-games/).

It would solve all your problems at once. You only need to [install Steam](https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb) on your Linux Computer.

Comment: I'm gonna try this now. I was hesitant to try steam because the game I hope to play is a online mmo with a stupidly paranoid anti-cheat system that things everything that is not the game is a hack (Game is ArcheAge). As for steam, doesn't steam only recognise the other computer as long as BOTH have internet and are logged in? I don't have a always-on internet connection...

Comment: Since [Arche Age is also on Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/304030/), I don't think it will ban you because you used a steam feature. If it does, then tell the developers they are amateurs. Anyway, in-home streaming also works in offline mode. It works over LAN, not Internet. You just need to log into Steam when you are online and make sure the "Don't save my credentials" option is not selected in the settings, which is the default. So you are good to go. However, you need Internet to play Arche Age.

Comment: I have tried said method, and in general it works really well. Unfortionately ArcheAge crashes without any errors or logs (I assume it doesn't like steam streaming. It is worth to note however that I merely added the stand alone game to steam, and I have not yet tried to use the Steam-version of ArcheAge. (The question was about general gaming however, not about 1 specific game) I thank you very much for your help, pretty much all games work now, even the ESC key.

Comment: Also a note for people with a similar problem: You will not be able to control/see (or experiance other issues with) games that run as Administrator. I assume this is because normal processes are unable to manipulate elevated processes. To fix this simply start steam as an administrator and everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

Steam has in-home streaming and only requires steam on both computers. You can add non-steam games. I know from personal experience that non-steam games that launch with the steam overlay enabled can stream so your friends can watch you play: when they enabled the feature, I had a friend send a request and successfully connect and view my game while I was playing Diablo3.

I expect the same is true for remote gaming, **but I am not certain**

http://store.steampowered.com/streaming/

Comment: Steam Broadcast is different to Steam in-home Streaming. Broadcast is basically built-in "twitch.tv" while in-home streaming is playing games on a different computer.

Comment: // , Again with the mystery downvotes.